# Can not read /dev/video0

Tags: webcam, devices

Hello
I have read that all entries in /dev are set up to work as if they were regular files.
After plugging in my webcam, the OS creates /dev/video0 automatically.
I then do:

```
maxtor@lounge:~$ sudo cat /dev/video0 > vyd 
[sudo] password for maxtor: 
cat:/dev/video0: 
No such devicemaxtor@lounge:~$
```

I was hoping that it would put a frame of video in 'vyd'.
So why wont it?

Starting Cheese, next, works; so everything seems to be in order.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, that's not how the `/dev/videoX` interface works; you can't `cat` the device node to get a frame of video out.

There are a number of utilities to do this though, their suitability depending on what you're looking to do. For example, the `webcam` package can take a snapshot from a video device and upload it to the web.